# Compiling basic C file for the ARM processor

Tags: c, arm

I am using the Yagarto recompilation of the GCC toolchain. I am trying to compile this simple program to get an `.elf` executable:

```
int main(void)
{
    return(0);
}
```

When typing the command `arm-none-eabi-gcc main.c` I get the error message

> c:/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-exit.o):
>   In function `exit':
>   C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\stdlib/../../../../../newlib-1.19.0/newlib/libc/stdlib/exit.c:65:
>   undefined reference to`_exit' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have the ARM standard C library available in your build environment? Because your linker says "no".

Comment: It seems like I haven't. How can I get the ARM standard C library in my build environment?

Comment: always most common libraries have been included with the tool chain itself. either you might not properly configure the library path or you may need to explicitly link with the library.

Comment: btw, `return` is not function and you can write `return 0;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Newlib requires you to define an `_exit` symbol. There might also be other symbols that you have to provide to make newlib work: http://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Stubs

Something like this should be sufficient (assuming you are compiling for a microcontroller, don't do this when you have an OS):

```
.globl _exit
_exit:
    b     . // Loop until reset
```

Or in C:

```
void _exit(void) {
    while(1) {
        // Loop until reset
    }
}
```

BTW: you might want to disable interrupts before spinning.

EDIT: Maybe a litte bit extra information. Yagarto includes Newlib as libc, which is a library providing functions like `printf()`, `malloc()`, etc. However, it cannot know how to send a character to a screen or console (in case of printf), or how to exit in case you call `abort()` or `exit()`. Therefore, Newlib requires you to provide implementations of a few basic function, depending on what functionality of Newlib you use.

Answer (score 0):

It depends hugely on what platform you're running on, what platform you're compiling for, what toolchain you're using, etc. There isn't a simple answer.

That said, CodeSourcery (now Mentor) do a decent turnkey cross-compilation environment --- it's just gcc and glibc compiled for your platform, but it's still a good place to start if you want to get set up easily:

http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/

Unfortunately when Mentor bought CodeSourcery they made the download procedure substantially harder than it used to be, and now you have to register and get a link sent to you by email rather than just downloading something, but I've yet to find a less bad way to get a gcc toolchain. (Suggestions wanted...)