# Compiling using GNU Tools for windows

Tags: windows, gcc, arm, eabi

I am trying to compile a thumb code using gcc (from  [GNU Tools ARM Embedded](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded)).

by typing the command line `gcc.exe C:\foo.c -o foo.o -mthumb` I get the following errors:

> c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/5.2 2015q4/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb\libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':
>   exit.c:(.text.exit+0x1a): undefined reference to`_exit'
>   c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/5.2 2015q4/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb\libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
>   sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0xc): undefined reference to`_sbrk'
>   c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/5.2 2015q4/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb\libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): In function `_write_r':
>   writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x10): undefined reference to`_write'
>   c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/5.2 2015q4/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb\libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): In function `_close_r':
>   closer.c:(.text._close_r+0xc): undefined reference to`_close'
>   c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/5.2 2015q4/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb\libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): In function `_lseek_r':
>   lseekr.c:(.text._lseek_r+0x10): undefined reference to`_lseek'
>   c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/5.2 2015q4/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb\libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): In function `_read_r':
>   readr.c:(.text._read_r+0x10): undefined reference to`_read'
>   c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/5.2 2015q4/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb\libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function `_fstat_r':
>   fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0xe): undefined reference to`_fstat'
>   c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/5.2 2015q4/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb\libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function `_isatty_r':
>   isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0xc): undefined reference to`_isatty'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

How can I solve these errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling basic C file for the ARM processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632595/compiling-basic-c-file-for-the-arm-processor)

Comment: Still cannot solve the problem according to the solution...

Comment: The solution is to implement (or pull in from your vendor's BSP code, as appropriate) the necessary functions - I can pretty much guarantee that it'll link successfully if they correctly exist. This is a bare-metal toolchain; in the absence of an OS [you have to handle the C library's "system call" requests yourself](https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Stubs).